# Do other operating systems implement the Linux system call splice?

Tags: sockets, operating-system, implementation, system-calls, splice

In an application I am developing I use [`splice`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splice_%28system_call%29) on Linux for socket-to-socket data transfer.

1. Do other operating systems (specifically at least Windows, OS X and FreeBSD) implement `splice` or an equivalent solution?
2. Is it possible to imitate socket-to-socket data `splice`ing on Windows with `sendfile`¹ + `memmap`¹?

---

¹ Both exist on Windows under different names which I do not remember.

---

**Update**

You can see the performance improvements of `splice` vs user space buffers on Linux.

[image: go]

- `DF`, `DR`, `F`, `MF`, `MR` are my application in its different tunneling modes, `NX` is NGINX web server
- `-p+t` uses the Linux system call `splice`
- `+p-t` uses a portable implementation with user space buffers
- `+p+t` uses a portable implementation with user space buffers and multiple OS threads
- bars represent throughput in **gigaBYTE** s per second
- a single 1 gigabyte (1048576000 bytes) file was requsted 4 times by 4 concurrent clients

Comment: I have some thoughts on this. But before I answer, let me ask, "what are you really trying do?"  Are you trying to echo a data stream or packets from one socket onto another? Do you need to inspect the data before sending it on?

Comment: Echo only echo. I am working on a simple tunneling solution called [PortFusion](http://fusion.corsis.eu) which has no need to inspect data streams (but if it ever does, I can switch to a portable implementation which brings data to user space).

Comment: @selbie I just added a chart to demonstrate why I am interested in `splice`-equivalents in other operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenBSD has `sosplice` and `somove`: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sosplice

Answer (score 1):

[TransmitFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) comes to mind as one such way in winsock to stream from one file handle to a socket, but I an not certain if that will help you as it's for streaming from file->disk.  You might be able to use it with a [memory mapped file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) handle.

I've heard a few people in the past speak of "kernel mode" as the way to speed up some echo and simple server operations, but I've never done it.

Some links on kernel mode winsock:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2006/02/24/introduction-to-winsock-kernel-wsk.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff571084(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: TransmitFile seems rather `File -> Socket` to me :) and I am all for trying memory mapped files but the part for receiving data from a socket directly to a memory mapped file without ever touching it in user space is missing, a zero-copy function of type `Socket -> File`.